# How to build a Gallery Application on Redis?

Tags: redis

I am trying to understand how to build application using Redis.
How can i handle the following use case with redis? (a image gallery with folders):

### Users Collection

id: Number,
userName: String

### Gallery Folders Collection

id: Number
userId: Number
folderName: String

### Gallery

id: Number
userId: Number
folderId: Number
galleryName: String
pageViews: Number

### Images

id: Number
galleryId: Number
imageUrl: String

How can i Query the Gallery with redis?
    1. Sometimes i want to filter the results by galleryName (for Search)
    2. Sometimes i want to filter the results by galleryName (for Search) + Only galleries from userId
    3. Sometimes i want to filter the results by galleryName (for Search) + Only galleries from userId + Sort by Page Views Descending
    4. Sometimes i want to get the Gallery just by id or id's

what's the best structure in Redis for this mission?

Comment: I am no expert on Redis, but I understand it to be a short-term data-structure cache and not a long-term primary datastore. I am happy to be told I am wrong if someone knows better. I also don't see a need for blinding speed in your application and suspect you may be better served by a traditional database. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3010345 Good luck with your project anyway!

Comment: Hi mark, thank you for your answer. I already working with mongodb, it's just a use case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is the following one:

- Each entity should be represented by a *hash* data structure, where the key is the entity `id` and the value is the JSON-serialized entity instance containing the rest of properties including or excluding the `id`.
- To implement filters, you need to index your data in *sets* and *sorted sets*, and sometimes in *lists*. For example, if you want to get all galleries which start with `a` you might build a *set* called `galleries:byname:a` where you'll store all gallery ids which start by `a`. In the other hand, if you want to find all galleries which match a tag or keyword, you'll need a *set* called `galleries:bykeyword:family` (where the keyword is **family**).
- To get all galleries which match a keyword you would need to execute a `smembers` or `sscan` command against `galleries:bykeyword:family`, get all gallery identifiers and get full objects to get galleries's metadata using `hmget` command against the hash of full gallery objects. `hmget` let you give one or more *keys* and get their value in a single command/operation.

There're many approaches. It might depend on the size of your data. You should take a look at [`scan`-based](http://redis.io/commands/scan) commands.

The point here is, when you think about a data strategy with Redis, you need to tailor your solution like a *manual index of data*. You can't expect queries, but storing the data in a way you can get by some criteria *as is*. That is, you need to understand very well what data structures support Redis and use them carefully to build a good data strategy and also think about performance. Also, a good advise is in NoSQL world data redudancy is fine if you get more performance.

Anyway, there's no definitive answer to your question. Now you need to make your own R&D!

Comment: Hi Matias, Thank you! one last question if it's ok... How you combine two or more conditions? Should i use SINTER for that?

Comment: @MomosMorbias It's an option (the thing about `sinter`). You can also build a *set* of that combined criteria.